# PHP Find a 15 or 16-digit number in a long string

Tags: php, regex, sanitization

I am working on a function to sanitize credit card data by replacing all digits except the last 4 with X's. the problem is that I have a lot of data already stored in the database as json objects. each record may or may not have a card number somewhere in it, and they occur in different places in the text from record to record (sometimes at the very end, sometimes in the middle, etc.) Looking for a way to extract all 15-digit or 16-digit numbers from the string so that I can pass this number to the sanitize function.

Comment: JSON strings or JSON objects? If they're stored as JSON strings, then the best solution would be to decode them into an array and then do the processing.

Comment: If the data is already in JSON, treat it as JSON and note a plain string . . .

Comment: "each record may or may not have a card number somewhere in it". Ouch! I hope that you are doing this to _quickly_ come into PCI-DSS compliance before you're heavily fined for data security violations. Plain text credit card numbers must never be stored, and there are regulations about how they must be split up and/or encrypted (as well as all sorts of logical and physical access controls to the data). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

> Looking for a way to extract all 15-digit or 16-digit numbers from the string

You can use:

```
\b[0-9]{15,16}\b
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP You can use like this:

```
<?php
$subject="aa999999999999999aa888888888888888as555555ssd555fs22aa999999999999999a";//Your string
preg_match_all('/(?:[0-9]{15,16})+/s', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$result = $result[0];

print_r($result);//Printing result
```

**output:**

```
Array ( [0] => 999999999999999 [1] => 888888888888888 [2] => 999999999999999 )
```

if you want only one and first number then you can use this instead:

```
if (preg_match('/([0-9]{15,16})/s', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[0];
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If it is stored as a json object in the DB and you want to find an attribute in the object you'll want to use [json_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to take the record and make it a php Stdclass.

so if the json record looks like this:

```
$record = "{ 'name' : 'theSpurg', 'cc_num' : '139764518623' }"
```

You can access it like this

```
$test = json_decode($record);
$credi_num = $test->cc_num;
```

if that's not what you're looking for then I am misunderstanding the situation.
Cheers