# find and replace 15/16 digit numbers

Tags: replace, find

I can see partial answers to my question but nothing that entirely answers my problem.

I'm looking for some script to run that will find and replace specifically only 15 and 16 digit numbers in a file.

rather than replace it with any one specific thing uniformly I want to retain the first 10 digits of the number and replace the last 6 with six  'X's

For example:

1234567890123456 would become: 1234567890XXXXXX

Help greatly appreciated.

P.S= The same question is raised here but only the question given in the subject title is addressed and not the detail of the text (the chap wanted not only to find 15 and 16 digit numbers... but wanted to replace the last digits with 'X')
[PHP Find a 15 or 16-digit number in a long string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616577/php-find-a-15-or-16-digit-number-in-a-long-string)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're using php.

With `preg_replace` you could do:

```
$str = 1234567890123456;
$res = preg_replace('/\b(\d{10})\d{5,6}\d/', '$1XXXXXX', $res);
```

**Explanation:**

```
/         : regex delimiter
\b        : word boundary, make sure we don't have digits before
(         : begin capture group
  \d{10}  : 10 digits
)         : end capture group
\d{5,6}   : 5 or 6 digits
\b        : word boundary, make sure we don't have digits before
/         : regex delimiter
```